# ImportError: bad magic number in 'encodings' при компиляции скрипта python в exe

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот ошибка:

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system
>   codec ImportError: bad magic number in 'encodings': b'3\r\r\n'
>
> Current thread 0x00000f98 (most recent call first):

Помогите пожалуйста. Версия питона 3.6.0. В питоне 3.4.4 было все нормально.

Comment: Чем компилируете?

Comment: Добавте больше информации - среда, компилятор и т.д..

Comment: Через cx_Frezee